# java.sql.SQLException: [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I get above error while trying to connect oracle 12c. I try using ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 jar files. I found below comment

------------------->

Bug 14575666

In 12.1, the default value for the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter has been updated to 11. This means that database clients using pre-11g JDBC thin drivers cannot authenticate to 12.1 database servers unless theSQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter is set to the old default of 8.

This will cause a 10.2.0.5 Oracle RAC database creation using DBCA to fail with the ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error in 12.1 Oracle ASM and Oracle Grid Infrastructure environments.

Workaround: Set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file.

<-------------------

I have one dought to implement above workaround as we have shared database.

If I set  SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file will it affect other users ?

Will it affect shared applications and its functionality ?

Comment: It implements backward client compatibility, so if the logon_version is lower it connects wider array of client versions, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Will it affect user and applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in sqlnet.ora affects all connections to the server. You're allowing user authentication with older versions of the password verifier and it affects all users. You can't allow it for just one user. But this isn't going to break other applications that can already connect successfully. It will allow older applications (that use old drivers) to connect too. The best solution is to upgrade all clients if possible but this setting is the workaround and it was made available for this exact purpose.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts for writing this